# Migrating Spring 3.1 to Spring 4: org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextFactoryBean

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, servlets

I´m migrating a Spring 3.1 + Hibernate 4 Web application to a Jboss 6.1 server with Spring 4.0.5 and Hibernate 4. Here´s my problem, in the original project, in my "applicationContext.xml" exists a bean like this one :

`<bean id="servletContext" class="org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextFactoryBean"/>`

My problem is that Spring 4 doesn´t have that library anymore. I need to know if exist an equivalent way to define this bean in Spring 4.0.5. I really apreciated any help can give me.

This is how looks my code where I use the servletContext Bean:

```
public class Environment {

    private Logs log;           

    private ServletContext context;
    private Scheduler quartzSched;
    private SocketPool socketPool;
    private WorkerSocket workerSocket;
    private SocketPoolFactory socketPoolFactory;
    private JsonObject catalog;
    private HashMap<String, Object> connections;

    private TerminalDao terminalDao;
    private TerminalItemDao terminalItemDao;
    private UsuarioDao usuarioDao;
    private PaymentSystemDao paymentSystemDao;
    private MensajeDao  mensajeDao; 
    private TransacDao transacDao;
    private TermPaySysDao termPaySysDao;
    private ComprobanteDao comprobanteDao;
    private String paymentSystem;


    public Environment(String paymentSystem, boolean setSchedulerFactoryBean) throws Exception {
        super();
        this.paymentSystem = paymentSystem;
        ApplicationContext ctx =  new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
        Services services = (Services) ctx.getBean("Services");         
        this.catalog = services.getCatalog();
        this.connections = services.getConnections();       
        this.transacDao = (TransacDao) ctx.getBean("transacDao");
        this.terminalDao = (TerminalDao) ctx.getBean("terminalDao");
        this.usuarioDao = (UsuarioDao) ctx.getBean("usuarioDao");
        this.terminalItemDao = (TerminalItemDao) ctx.getBean("terminalItemDao");
        this.paymentSystemDao = (PaymentSystemDao) ctx.getBean("paymentSystemDao");
        this.mensajeDao = (MensajeDao) ctx.getBean("mensajeDao");
        this.termPaySysDao = (TermPaySysDao) ctx.getBean("termPaySysDao");
        this.comprobanteDao = (ComprobanteDao) ctx.getBean("comprobanteDao");


        if(setSchedulerFactoryBean)
            this.quartzSched = (Scheduler) ctx.getBean("schedulerFactoryBean");; //OJO CON ESTO este deberia salir bien

        JsonObject PS = catalog.get(paymentSystem).getAsJsonObject();

        if(PS.get("ConnectionType").getAsString().equals("SocketPool")){
            this.socketPool = (SocketPool) services.getConnections().get(paymentSystem+"_SocketPool");
            this.socketPoolFactory = (SocketPoolFactory) services.getConnections().get(paymentSystem+"_SocketPoolFactory");     
        }else {
            this.socketPool = null;
            this.socketPoolFactory = null;      
        }
        this.workerSocket = null;

        this.context = (ServletContext)ctx.getBean("servletContext"); //HERE I USE THE BEAN
        this.log= new Logs();


    }
```

Here I add Services.java, this is my class that use ServletContext as parameter.

```
package com.globalcca.pos_movil_tran.services;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileFilter;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.Set;


import javax.servlet.ServletContext;


import org.apache.commons.beanutils.ConvertUtils;
import org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool.Config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import com.globalcca.pos_movil_desc.modelo.Transac;
import com.globalcca.posmovil.resourceManager.SocketPool;
import com.globalcca.posmovil.resourceManager.SocketPoolFactory;
import com.globalcca.posmovil.resourceManager.WorkerSocket;
import com.globalcca.posmovil.util.DateConverter;
import com.globalcca.posmovil.util.TransacConverter;
import com.globalcca.posmovil.util.PaymentSystemConverter;
import com.globalcca.pos_movil_desc.modelo.PaymentSystem;
import com.globalcca.pos_movil_desc.modelo.Transac;
import com.google.gson.JsonArray;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.google.gson.JsonParser;
import com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader;

public class Services {

JsonObject catalog;
static HashMap<String, Object> connections;
static Config SocketPoolConfig = new Config();
private static Logs log = new Logs();
@Autowired ServletContext servletContext;

public Services( ServletContext context) throws IOException{

    ConvertUtils.register(new DateConverter(), java.util.Date.class);
    ConvertUtils.register(new TransacConverter(), Transac.class);               //Se arreglo TransacConverter
    //ConvertUtils.register(new PaymentSystemConverter(), PaymentSystem.class);

    FileFilter fileFilter = new FileFilter() {
        public boolean accept(File file) {
            return file.isDirectory();
        }
    };      
    File dir = new File(context.getRealPath("/WEB-INF/classes/Adquiriente/"));
    readSocketPoolProperties(context);

    JsonObject catalog = new JsonObject();
    connections = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
    // This filter only returns directories
    File[] files = dir.listFiles(fileFilter);
    if (files == null) {
        System.out.println("Either dir does not exist or is not a directory");
    } else {
        for (int i=0; i<files.length; i++) 
        {
            // Get path of directory
            String dirpath = files[i].getAbsolutePath();
            String dirname = files[i].getName();
            String catalogPath = dirpath+"/Catalog.cfg";
            String ConnectionModuleConfigPath = dirpath+"/ConnectionModule.cfg";

            try{
                JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(catalogPath)));
                JsonObject PaymentSystem = (JsonObject)parser.parse(reader);                    
                catalog.add(dirname,PaymentSystem);
                //initConnection(PaymentSystem,ConnectionModuleConfigPath,parser,dirname);      //Descomentar esto cuando tengamos las conexiones
                log.info("Loading "+catalogPath+" Successful");
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                log.error("Error parsing Catalog.cfg File");
            } 

        }
        this.setCatalog(catalog);
    }   
}

public static void readSocketPoolProperties(ServletContext context){
    String  SocketPoolProp = "/WEB-INF/classes/SocketPool.properties";
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    Boolean error = false; 
    try {
        SocketPoolProp = context.getRealPath(SocketPoolProp);
        prop.load(new FileInputStream(SocketPoolProp));
        SocketPoolConfig.maxIdle = Integer.parseInt(prop.getProperty("MaxIdle"));
        SocketPoolConfig.maxActive = Integer.parseInt(prop.getProperty("MaxActive"));
        SocketPoolConfig.minEvictableIdleTimeMillis = Long.parseLong(prop.getProperty("MinEvictableIdleTimeMillis"));
        SocketPoolConfig.testOnBorrow = Boolean.parseBoolean(prop.getProperty("TestOnBorrow"));
        SocketPoolConfig.maxWait = Long.parseLong(prop.getProperty("MaxWait"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.error("Error Loading SocketPool.properties File");
        error = true;
    }

    if(error){
        log.info("Using Default Values for SocketPool config");
        SocketPoolConfig = new Config();
        SocketPoolConfig.maxIdle = SocketPool.DEFAULT_MAX_IDLE;
        SocketPoolConfig.maxActive = SocketPool.DEFAULT_MAX_ACTIVE;
        SocketPoolConfig.minEvictableIdleTimeMillis = SocketPool.DEFAULT_MIN_EVICTABLE_IDLE_TIME_MILLIS;
        SocketPoolConfig.testOnBorrow = SocketPool.DEFAULT_TEST_ON_BORROW;
        SocketPoolConfig.maxWait = SocketPool.DEFAULT_MAX_WAIT;
    }else{
        log.info("Loading "+SocketPoolProp+" Successful");
    }
}

public static void initConnection(JsonObject PaymentSystem, String ConnectionModuleConfigPath, JsonParser parser,String PSName) {

    JsonReader reader;
    try {
        reader = new JsonReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(ConnectionModuleConfigPath)));

    JsonObject ConnectionsConfig = (JsonObject)parser.parse(reader);                    

    if(ConnectionsConfig.get("Type").getAsString().equals("SocketPool")){
        initSocketPool(PaymentSystem, ConnectionModuleConfigPath,parser,PSName, ConnectionsConfig);
        log.info("Initialization of SocketPool Successful");

    }else if(ConnectionsConfig.get("Type").getAsString().equals("ServerSocket")){
        initServerSocket(PaymentSystem, ConnectionModuleConfigPath,parser,PSName, ConnectionsConfig); 
        log.info("Initialization of ServerSocket Successful");

    }
    PaymentSystem.addProperty("ConnectionType", ConnectionsConfig.get("Type").getAsString());

    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.error("Error Initializing Connections");
        log.error(e);
    }

}


private static void initServerSocket(JsonObject PaymentSystem, String socketConfigPath, JsonParser parser,String PSName, JsonObject ConnectionsConfig) throws IOException{

    JsonObject address = ConnectionsConfig.getAsJsonObject("Connections");

    Set<Map.Entry<String, JsonElement>> map = address.entrySet();
    Iterator<Map.Entry<String, JsonElement>> iterator = map.iterator();
    int size = map.size();
    WorkerSocket [] sSockets = new WorkerSocket[size];

    for( int k = 0; k < size; k++ )
    { 
        String IP = iterator.next().getKey();
        int port = address.get(IP).getAsInt();
        sSockets[k] = new WorkerSocket(IP, port);
        log.trace("Server Socket IP:"+IP+" Port:"+port+" Initialized");
        iterator.remove();  
    }
    connections.put(PSName+"_sSockets", sSockets);

}

private static void initSocketPool(JsonObject PaymentSystem, String socketConfigPath, JsonParser parser,String PSName, JsonObject ConnectionsConfig){

    SocketPoolFactory spf = new SocketPoolFactory();
    SocketPool sp = new SocketPool(spf,SocketPoolConfig);
    JsonObject address = ConnectionsConfig.getAsJsonObject("Connections");
    try {           

        Set<Map.Entry<String, JsonElement>> map = address.entrySet();
        Iterator<Map.Entry<String, JsonElement>> iterator = map.iterator();
        int size = map.size();

        for( int k = 0; k < size; k++ )
        { 
            String IP = iterator.next().getKey();
            JsonArray Sockets = address.getAsJsonArray(IP);

            for(int i=0;i<Sockets.size();i++)
            {
                JsonArray Ports = Sockets.get(i).getAsJsonArray();
                int first = Ports.get(0).getAsInt();
                int dif = Ports.get(1).getAsInt()-first+1;
                for(int j=0;j<dif;j++)
                {
                    sp.addSocket(IP,first+j);
                    log.trace("Pool Socket IP:"+IP+" Port:"+first+j+" Added");
                }
            }
            iterator.remove();
        }


    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error(e);
    }

    connections.put(PSName+"_SocketPool", sp);
    connections.put(PSName+"_SocketPoolFactory",spf);
}

public HashMap<String, Object> getConnections() {
    return connections;
}


public JsonObject getCatalog() {
    return catalog;
}

public void setCatalog(JsonObject catalog) {
    this.catalog = catalog;
}
```

}

and this is my ApplicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <beans default-autowire="byName" 
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config/>

    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" >
            <value>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</value>
        </property>
        <property name="url">
            <value>jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.0.0.66:1521:bgw</value>
        </property> 
        <property name="username">
            <value>POSMOVIL</value>
        </property>
        <property name="password">
            <value>ORACLE</value>
        </property>
    </bean>


        <!-- Definición de la fábrica de sesiones de Hibernate administrada por Spring -->
    <!-- Mapeo de Hibernate de archivos hbm.xml -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="mappingResources">
            <list>
                <value>com/globalcca/pos_movil_desc/modelo/Afiliado.hbm.xml</value>
                <value>com/globalcca/pos_movil_desc/modelo/App.hbm.xml</value>
                <value>com/globalcca/pos_movil_desc/modelo/Approl.hbm.xml</value>
                <value>com/globalcca/pos_movil_desc/modelo/Archivo.hbm.xml</value>
                <value>com/globalcca/pos_movil_desc/modelo/Banco.hbm.xml</value>
                <value>com/globalcca/pos_movil_desc/modelo/BloquesHorarios.hbm.xml</value>
                <value>com/globalcca/pos_movil_desc/modelo/Calendario.hbm.xml</value>
                <value>com/globalcca/pos_movil_desc/modelo/Capk.hbm.xml</value>
                <value>com/globalcca/pos_movil_desc/modelo/Comprobante.hbm.xml</value>
                <value>com/globalcca/pos_movil_desc/modelo/Config.hbm.xml</value>
                <value>com/globalcca/pos_movil_desc/modelo/ConstanteCalendario.hbm.xml</value>
                <value>com/globalcca/pos_movil_desc/modelo/Contactos.hbm.xml</value>
                <value>com/globalcca/pos_movil_desc/modelo/Crl.hbm.xml</value>
                <value>com/globalcca/pos_movil_desc/modelo/Dispone.hbm.xml</value>
                <value>com/globalcca/pos_movil_desc/modelo/Disponibilidad.hbm.xml</value>
                <value>com/globalcca/pos_movil_desc/modelo/Dominio.hbm.xml</value>
                <value>com/globalcca/pos_movil_desc/modelo/Funcion.hbm.xml</value>
                <value>com/globalcca/pos_movil_desc/modelo/Hclaves.hbm.xml</value>
                <value>com/globalcca/pos_movil_desc/modelo/Horario.hbm.xml</value>
                <value>com/globalcca/pos_movil_desc/modelo/Horariodia.hbm.xml</value>
                <value>com/globalcca/pos_movil_desc/modelo/MasterKey.hbm.xml</value>
                <value>com/globalcca/pos_movil_desc/modelo/Mensaje.hbm.xml</value>
                <value>com/globalcca/pos_movil_desc/modelo/Modulo.hbm.xml</value>
                <value>com/globalcca/pos_movil_desc/modelo/Operador.hbm.xml</value>
                <value>com/globalcca/pos_movil_desc/modelo/PaymentSystem.hbm.xml</value>
                <value>com/globalcca/pos_movil_desc/modelo/Rol.hbm.xml</value>
                <value>com/globalcca/pos_movil_desc/modelo/Sitio.hbm.xml</value>
                <value>com/globalcca/pos_movil_desc/modelo/Solicitud.hbm.xml</value>
                <value>com/globalcca/pos_movil_desc/modelo/Tarea.hbm.xml</value>
                <value>com/globalcca/pos_movil_desc/modelo/Tarearol.hbm.xml</value>
                <value>com/globalcca/pos_movil_desc/modelo/TarjetaHabiente.hbm.xml</value>
                <value>com/globalcca/pos_movil_desc/modelo/Terminal.hbm.xml</value>
                <value>com/globalcca/pos_movil_desc/modelo/Terminalitem.hbm.xml</value>
                <value>com/globalcca/pos_movil_desc/modelo/Termpaysys.hbm.xml</value>
                <value>com/globalcca/pos_movil_desc/modelo/Transac.hbm.xml</value>
                <value>com/globalcca/pos_movil_desc/modelo/Usuario.hbm.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>

        <!-- Conexion a la BD especificada en WEB-INF/applicationContex.xml -->

        <property name="dataSource">
            <ref bean="dataSource" />
        </property>

        <!-- Propiedades de Hibernate -->
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.use_sql_comments">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Configuración del repositorio de datos persistentes -->

     <!--
    <bean id="servletContext" class="org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextFactoryBean"/>

    -->
    <bean id="Services" class="com.globalcca.pos_movil_tran.services.Services">
        <constructor-arg name="context" ref="servletContext"/>  
    </bean>

    <!-- Definición de las implementaciones (utilizando Hibernate) de los DAO'S -->
    <bean id="afiliadoDao" class="com.globalcca.pos_movil_tran.dao.impl.AfiliadoDaoHibernate"/>
    <bean id="archivoDao" class="com.globalcca.pos_movil_tran.dao.impl.ArchivoDaoHibernate"/>
    <bean id="bancoDao" class="com.globalcca.pos_movil_tran.dao.impl.BancoDaoHibernate"/>
    <bean id="bloqueoDao" class="com.globalcca.pos_movil_tran.dao.impl.BloqueDaoHibernate"/>
    <bean id="calendarioDao" class="com.globalcca.pos_movil_tran.dao.impl.CalendarioDaoHibernate"/>
    <bean id="comprobanteDao" class="com.globalcca.pos_movil_tran.dao.impl.ComprobanteDaoHibernate"/>
    <bean id="configDao" class="com.globalcca.pos_movil_tran.dao.impl.ConfigDaoHibernate"/>
    <bean id="constanteCalendarioDao" class="com.globalcca.pos_movil_tran.dao.impl.ConstanteCalendarioDaoHibernate"/>
    <bean id="disponeDao" class="com.globalcca.pos_movil_tran.dao.impl.DisponeDaoHibernate"/>
    <bean id="disponibilidadDao" class="com.globalcca.pos_movil_tran.dao.impl.DisponibilidadDaoHibernate"/>
    <bean id="dominioDao" class="com.globalcca.pos_movil_tran.dao.impl.DominioDaoHibernate"/>
    <bean id="horarioDao" class="com.globalcca.pos_movil_tran.dao.impl.HorarioDaoHibernate"/>
    <bean id="horarioDiaDao" class="com.globalcca.pos_movil_tran.dao.impl.HorarioDiaDaoHibernate"/>
    <bean id="mensajeDao" class="com.globalcca.pos_movil_tran.dao.impl.MensajeDaoHibernate"/>
    <bean id="operadorDao" class="com.globalcca.pos_movil_tran.dao.impl.OperadorDaoHibernate"/>
    <bean id="paymentSystemDao" class="com.globalcca.pos_movil_tran.dao.impl.PaymentSystemDaoHibernate"/>
    <bean id="sitioDao" class="com.globalcca.pos_movil_tran.dao.impl.SitioDaoHibernate"/>
    <bean id="solicitudDao" class="com.globalcca.pos_movil_tran.dao.impl.SolicitudDaoHibernate"/>
    <bean id="tarjetaHabienteDao" class="com.globalcca.pos_movil_tran.dao.impl.TarjetaHabienteDaoHibernate"/>
    <bean id="terminalDao" class="com.globalcca.pos_movil_tran.dao.impl.TerminalDaoHibernate"/>
    <bean id="terminalItemDao" class="com.globalcca.pos_movil_tran.dao.impl.TerminalItemDaoHibernate"/>
    <bean id="termPaySysDao" class="com.globalcca.pos_movil_tran.dao.impl.TermPaySysDaoHibernate"/>
    <bean id="transacDao" class="com.globalcca.pos_movil_tran.dao.impl.TransacDaoHibernate"/>
    <bean id="usuarioDao" class="com.globalcca.pos_movil_tran.dao.impl.UsuarioDaoHibernate"/>

    <!-- Definición del manejador de transacciones de Spring -->
    <bean id="transactionManager"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Activar el comportamiento transaccional de los métodos y -->
    <!-- clases anotados como @Transactional                      -->
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />


    <bean id="schedulerFactoryBean" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean" lazy-init="false">
        <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:./classes/quartz.properties"/>
        <property name="waitForJobsToCompleteOnShutdown" value="false" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="applicationContextSchedulerContextKey">
            <value>applicationContext</value>
        </property>
        <property name="autoStartup">
                <value>true</value>
        </property>     
    </bean>
```

The Services bean use the servlet context, and i use this bean in the Environment class. Can You give a solution with @Autowired?

Can someone take this code and give an example of how to use @Autowired??

I try to use @Autowired in my class Services and still giving me null.

Please i need help

Comment: From the [javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/web/context/support/ServletContextFactoryBean.html): Deprecated. as of Spring 3.0, since "servletContext" is now available as a default bean in every WebApplicationContext. SO you can remove and directly @Autowire servletContext

Comment: Please can you give me an example? I don´t understand how to use @Autowire.

Comment: I add my code to the original post, could you give me a solution with the @Autowired? please

Comment: You can remove `<bean id="servletContext" .. ` and it should work **as is**

Comment: Could you take the code in my post and give me an example? Im getting null value for the servletContext

Comment: I edit my post to add my new services class with @Autowired and add my applicationContext.xml. Im getting Null value, please help

Answer (score 4):

You don't really need this bean anymore, just go ahead and remove it, where ever you have injected servletContext, it should just work this way:

```
@Autowired
ServletContext context;
```

Comment: The usage does not look right Pedro, I am assuming you have a webapplication, if so you don't create the application context this way, there are easier ways to do it(through ContextLoaderListener). can you please also show how you are using servletcontext - I may be able to show you a better example based on your usage

Comment: What do you mean with "show how you are using servletcontext"? do you want to see the files "applicationContext.xml" and "web.xml" or my servlet where i invoke my class environment?

Comment: I add Services.java, this is where i use servlet context. Please Mr  Kunjummen, i need you help.

Comment: That is essentially it @Pedro, in your `com.globalcca.pos_movil_tran.services.Services` class just add an `@Autowired ServletContext servletContext`, and also just ensure that you have a `<context:annotation-config/>` in your applicationContext.xml file and it should just work

Comment: com.globalcca.pos_movil_tran.services.Services is the class Services I show you in my post, can you tell me where should go? because as you see i dont have a @Autowired ServletContext servletContext attribute. I should keep the services bean?

Comment: I dont know where to put the @Autowired, Im getting null value for the servlet context and this <context:annotation-config/> give my troubles went I deploy the project in my Jboss, says that dont reconize it

Comment: Hi, I make <context:annotation-config/> works but i´m still having Null value for the Servlet context. Im gonna edit my post im show you how looks com.globalcca.pos_movil_tran.services.Services with the @Autowired and my Application Context. Please help me